What does {aaa, aab, baa}* equal to?
The answer should be formulated as a property of the lengths of consecutive blocks of identical letters.
So, it can't be given using some algorithm or recursive methods. Verification of belonging to the language must be a linear condition. I can easily describe some properties of such words.
But how do I come up with the criteria for such words? If you say that the number of letters is divisible by 3, blocks of 'b' consist either of one or two letters, between blocks of 'b' the number of letters 'a' is either 2 + 3k or 4 + 3k and the first (last) block of 'b' has 3k or 2 + 3k letters 'a' before (after), etc., it is still not enough, as you can come up with the counterexample of a word that doesn't belong to the language. Or am I overthinking this and the answer is much simpler?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

What do you mean by linear condition here? Do you want an $O(n)$ algorithm to verify if some string $w$ (with $|w|=n$) is in this language? Will that suffice?

Surely you're taking a formallàguages course? Have you tried to convert the regex to a DFA and minimize it?
